# Is there a way to see which apps are using GCM?

Tags: battery-life, push-notifications

I'm interested to know how many of the apps I have installed are using GCM.  Is there a way to find out?

Answer (score 4):

In `Settings -> Applications`, in the permissions section, tap on `Show All` and under `Network Communication` there should be `Receive data from internet` if the application has requested push (GCM) permission.

*Tested on 4.1.2, labels and positions may differ.*

Comment: Wow, could they possibly have come up with a more mystified way to describe GCM / C2DM in the user interface?!  I was honestly very skeptical of your answer, until I looked around, and indeed those apps that "receive data from the internet" don't have the "Receive data from internet" permission, but only those might that (might) implement GCM do!

Comment: @cnst: Well, there's a bit of logic in how it is worded, it kind of plays on the syntax : the app doesn't `fetch`, doesn't `request` the push, it `receives` the push! :P You must read it in reverse : "Internet sends data to my app".

Comment: @cnst: So, to be sure, I made an app (the basic Hello World when creating a project with Android Studio) and I only inserted `<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />` in the app's manifest : the only permission listed in the menu is `Receive data from internet`.

Answer (score 3):

You could try [Greenify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify&hl=en). It's an app for hibernating apps so that they don't take up a lot of resources; thus, improving battery life.

However, it also lists apps in a way that lets you see which ones support GCM.

[image]

Comment: looks very promising.  does it require a rooted device?

Comment: @cnst Documentation says it supports non-root, but not so sure for the hibernating features. Check it out. It's free anyway.

Comment: Cool, greenify is free and so easy to see which one uses GCM. Hopefully it retrieves the data from system instead of from some database. :D

Comment: Unfortunately, some apps (e.g. Facebook, Instagram, FB Messenger) request the GCM permission but still establish their own persistent background sockets and services.