# How to completely block popups / dialogs from WhatsApp without deleting the app?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, popup

I have a Nexus 5 phone with Android 6.0.1 and I'm trying to use it for time-lapse videos ("Lapse it" app) which means it needs to be on for many hours undisturbed.

The problem is that WhatsApp creates a dialog regularly which interrupts the time lapse photo app that I'm using.

I have disabled all notifications for WhatsApp, but this dialog comes up anyway.

Deleting WhatsApp would of course solve the problem, but it not possible for other reasons (message history etc stored). Registering the app would also stop the dialog, but is also not an option since I'm using the same number on another phone.

I think it should be possible to disable all dialogs, but since I've tried that and this dialog still comes up, what else is there? Is there a stronger blocking option? Can it be done if I root the phone?

Attaching screenshots of the notification and of the settings.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Rooting would definitely offer more powerful options but to root you'd need to unlock bootloader and that would wipe all data. It's the same as the option you are avoiding (uninstall whatsapp) // You can't anyway use the device when taking a time lapse, so the simplest would be to put it in airplane mode, isn't it? // your second screen shot is confusing - if it is not registered, how are you getting messages on WhatsApp? Unless you are using that SIM on another phone

Comment: Sorry, I missed seeing the edit where you clarified the last point. Simply use airplane mode to solve the problem

Comment: Technically, that's not an Android notification, but a custom pop-up dialog. In this case, you're right that blocking the notification won't help. Possibly there's a background *service* that checks this periodically and shows the dialog. If that's the case, it might be possible to disable this using `pm` command.

Comment: Related https://android.stackexchange.com/q/43970/131553

Comment: Related https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/52789/popups-dialogs-notifications-toasts-whats-the-difference?rq=1